# Get multiple values from the same select dropdown form field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I currently have a React Material form with a select dropdown, in which I map over an array of objects and display the name field as each option. I've currently set the option's value attribute to the object's name (cpuParent.name). However, the same object also has a wattage field (cpuParent.wattage), the value of which I also need. Is there a way that I can get both the name and the wattage of the object from the same dropdown field? I've copied and pasted the relevant snippets of my code below - the component is a class component:

Within the class component, but outside the render method:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        calculator: {
            cpuParent: '',
            cpuChild: 0
        }
    }
}

handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
        calculator: {
            ...this.state.calculator,
            [name]: event.target.value
        }
    });
};
```

Inside the render method:

```
// Destructure the state
const {calculator: {cpuParent, cpuChild}} = this.state;

// Destructure the props
const {classes, cpuParents} = this.props;

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <NativeSelect
        value={cpuParent}
        onChange={this.handleChange('cpuParent')}
        inputProps={{'aria-label': 'CPU Parent'}}
    >
        <option value="">Select Brand</option>
        {
            cpuParents.map(cpuParent => (
                <option key={cpuParent.id} value={cpuParent.name}>
                    {cpuParent.name}
                </option>
            ))
        }
    </NativeSelect>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: if you set value to index you can access whole object by index in handle change like `cpuParents[parseInt(event.target.value)]` or use custom attribute in option tag and get it from `event.target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You canno't get both name and wattage values but their is a trick: 
you can concatenate name and wattage with particular character in option value like `value={cpuParent.name + "_" + cpuParent.wattage }` and read the values in`handleChange` event function by splitting like
let `value = event.target.value.split('_')`

Answer (score 2):

You can get whole object just change your option value to whole object

```
<option key={cpuParent.id} value={cpuParent}>
                    {cpuParent.name}
                </option>
```

Now the label will display name, but value will hold whole object item.
you can access whichever value you need.

And you can access the attributes using

```
  [name]: event.target.value['name']
  [name]: event.target.value['wattage']
```